r-forestplot reduce space between rows
I would like to minimise the height of the rows so that it is consistent across different forrest plots which have varying numbers of rows.
I have tried lineheight = unit(8.6,"mm") but it doesn't seem to work
library(forestplot)

base_data <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(0.578, 0.165),
                            lower = c(0.372, 0.018),
                            upper = c(0.898, 1.517),
                            study = c("Auckland", "Block"),
                            deaths_steroid = c("36", "1"),
                            deaths_placebo = c("60", "5"),
                            OR = c("0.58", "0.16"))

base_data |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, deaths_steroid, deaths_placebo, OR),
             clip = c(0.1, 2.5),
             xlog = TRUE) |>
  fp_set_style(box = "royalblue",
               line = "darkblue",
               summary = "royalblue") |> 
  fp_add_header(study = c("", "Study"),
                deaths_steroid = c("Deaths", "(steroid)"),
                deaths_placebo = c("Deaths", "(placebo)"),
                OR = c("", "OR")) |>
  fp_append_row(mean  = 0.531,
                lower = 0.386,
                upper = 0.731,
                study = "Summary",
                OR = "0.53",
                is.summary = TRUE) |> 
  fp_set_zebra_style("#EFEFEF") ```


Please use library(forestplot) rather than require(forestplot). While require just returns FALSE if package is not found, library will throw an error which might be intended in this case.

The lineheight argument suggests that it will fix the height of rows in the plot, but I don't see that happening anywhere in the actual code -- it only gets passed into some functions that define the legend. Almost invariably R plots just scale to the size of the window they're being drawn in, so a more likely solution is to fix the size of that scaled by the number of rows you're plotting, or perhaps pad your plot with blank space to achieve the same number of total "rows".

There is an open issue with the lineheight argument, but there is a patch in the development branch you might try. First install the development version:
devtools::install_github("gforge/forestplot@develop")

Then we can test if the patch fixes the issue with lineheight:
20mm as a Test
library(forestplot)

base_data <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(0.578, 0.165),
                            lower = c(0.372, 0.018),
                            upper = c(0.898, 1.517),
                            study = c("Auckland", "Block"),
                            deaths_steroid = c("36", "1"),
                            deaths_placebo = c("60", "5"),
                            OR = c("0.58", "0.16"))

base_data |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, deaths_steroid, deaths_placebo, OR),
             clip = c(0.1, 2.5),
             lineheight =  unit(20,"mm"),
             xlog = TRUE) |>
  fp_set_style(box = "royalblue",
               line = "darkblue",
               summary = "royalblue") |> 
  fp_add_header(study = c("", "Study"),
                deaths_steroid = c("Deaths", "(steroid)"),
                deaths_placebo = c("Deaths", "(placebo)"),
                OR = c("", "OR")) |>
  fp_append_row(mean  = 0.531,
                lower = 0.386,
                upper = 0.731,
                study = "Summary",
                OR = "0.53",
                is.summary = TRUE) |> 
  fp_set_zebra_style("#EFEFEF")


8.6mm as Desired
base_data |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, deaths_steroid, deaths_placebo, OR),
             clip = c(0.1, 2.5),
             lineheight =  unit(8.6,"mm"),
             xlog = TRUE) |>
  fp_set_style(box = "royalblue",
               line = "darkblue",
               summary = "royalblue") |> 
  fp_add_header(study = c("", "Study"),
                deaths_steroid = c("Deaths", "(steroid)"),
                deaths_placebo = c("Deaths", "(placebo)"),
                OR = c("", "OR")) |>
  fp_append_row(mean  = 0.531,
                lower = 0.386,
                upper = 0.731,
                study = "Summary",
                OR = "0.53",
                is.summary = TRUE) |> 
  fp_set_zebra_style("#EFEFEF")


Created on 2024-04-22 with reprex v2.1.0
